# How can I create/skin a C# UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

Ive been working on a C# project for a while now and I fell it needs change its look.

I have found a UI kit that I really like, which can be seen below:
http://medialoot.com/item/transparent-ui-kit/

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: Im using WinForms

EDIT2: Maybe I should convert over to WPF? Is this doable?

Comment: Are you using WPF? ASP.NET? WinForms?

Comment: I can suggest you pay for it, but somehow I think that is not the answer you're looking for... :-)

Comment: _"I fell it needs change its look."_ - please, don't. Chances are you will be creating a monstrosity of an UI, but apart from the aesthetics the users aren't going to thank you for this. The grey Windows look may seem outdated, but people are used to applications obeying their system's theming.

Comment: I do understand where you are coming from. Big Companies like Anti Virus providers make horrid UI's, however my uses voted that they would prefer a different look.

Comment: I only worked with WPF and I know that theming is quite easy in WPF. If you are starting on building your application I could recommend moving on to WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a library of controls.  For you to have an appearance such as that  you'll have to create or acquire a similar library of controls and replace all your controls in your project to get that appearance.

If you want to update colors (background, foreground, etc.) and such you can make a class that recurses through controls and sets the settings using reflection and a switch statement to process each control.  Then just run this on each form before you show it.  One word of caution about this, some controls don't respect your changes and get overridden with themes from the OS (datetimerpicker being the biggest culprit).  You'll also need to consider whether your users will appreciate the extra work put in for color/appearance changes.

Comment: Thanks, although the example is just a set of images ready for people to make their own.

Comment: Whoops, silly me.  In that case you might be able to custom draw your controls by painting those images and the text on top of them.  You could try it with one control first (maybe a button) to see if it seems to work smoothly or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass most common controls and draw their appearance yourself. However, unless for novelty applications I doubt your users will thank you for doing so.

Comment: At least for stuff like "patchers", media players, game trainers, etc. people often like being able to use fancy themes. But for any serious application using the OS' default is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Our company actually had to do this when creating the POS software for their registers. The point was to fit the design and feel of the company.

Subclassing EVERY control you use is the way to go, and it can be a massive pain. If that is what your customers want, then go ahead.

I don't know about external kits like you referenced, since we just redesigned them all on our own.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have very good design skill and have a good know how about creating such templates, its better to buy them.

And C# is just a language. You're looking to create templates and skins for either for ASP.NET website/application or for windows forms.

Comment: No he wants to skin a WinForm.

Comment: He made the edit later to refer to WinForms. I wasn't sure so I referred to both webapps and winforms to start with. Y vote down? :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DevExpress Skins](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/)

If you can afford it.